# Java - Extract Interface to File

Tags: java

I have been trying and trying for a while with this and I just seem to cannot solve it.

I am supposed to extract classes from a Java-file and print in a shape UML-diagram, in the IDE or writing on a file

e.g the program

```
 public class Complex {
    private int re;
    private int im;

    public Complex(int re, int im) {
        this.re = re;
        this.im = im;
    }

    public Complex add(Complex h) {
        return new Complex(this.re + h.re, this.im + h.im);
    }

    public Complex sub(Complex h) {
        return new Complex(this.re - h.re, this.im - h.im);
    }

    public Complex mul(Complex h) {
        int a = re;
        int b = im;
        int c = h.re;
        int d = h.im;
        return new Complex(a * c - b * d, b * c + a * d);
    }

    public Complex div(Complex h) {
        int a = re;
        int b = im;
        int c = h.re;
        int d = h.im;
        return new Complex((a * c + b * d) / (c * c + d * d), (b * c - a * d)
                / (c * c + d * d));
    }

    public String toString() {
        if (im >= 0) {
            return re + " + " + im + "i";
        } else
            return re + "  " + im + "i";
    }
}
```

Should generate something like:

```
a Complex
b  int re
b  int re
a  Complex(re:int, im:int)
a  add():Complex
a  sub():Complex
a  mul():Complex
a  div():Complex
a  toString():String
a main()
```

I have started with stripping the first parenthesis from the file;

```
import java.io.*;

public class ClassExtract {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ClassExtract obj = new ClassExtract();
        obj.removeBracket("Complexx.txt");
    }

    public void removeBracket(String filnamn) {

        try {
            File f = new File(filnamn);
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(f);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("noparanthesis_" + filnamn);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

            String rad = br.readLine();
            while (rad != null) {
                rad = rad.replaceAll("\\(", " ");
                bw.write(rad);
                bw.newLine();
                rad = br.readLine();
            }

            bw.close();
            br.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.printf("The file " + filnamn + " was not found.");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.printf("Writing error.");
        }
    }
}
```

I have thought of different ways of approaching this problem. The way that I think would be easiest would be to strip everything after collected the head `public class Complex`, which would mean the rest of the file would look something like:

```
public Complex int re, int im
public Complex add Complex h
public Complex sub Complex h
```

etc and do the same and read the index of the lines.

I actually feel very lost and I have hard to tackle this problem, any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: do you need to parse the java?  or can you load the compiled class with a classloader and use reflection?

Comment: Yeah, I have to read a .java-file and make a .txt-file with the result or have it directly in my IDE console.

@Qwe
I am reading about reflection now, it seems it can be handy since it obtains the classes or such - but a little concrete example could help alot with how you think I could implement it.

Answer (score 1):

As Qwe says in the comment, you would be much better off looking at the Java [Reflection APIs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/).

These let you inspect a class and list its methods, superclasses, interfaces and so on.

By tackling this problem with regexes/text analysis, you are basically trying to write a partial Java parser, which is an entirely unnecessary amount of pain!

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean, The point is that Java will deal with all the textual details and just provide the high-level class relationships and method signatures that you need. Even if the .java is strangely formatted, for example!

Comment: Yeah, nevermind that comment, I thought wrong.


    Class aClass = MyObject.class
    Constructor[] constructors = aClass.getConstructors();

I am a bit confused..

Comment: Anyone?

I am currently experimenting with reflection-abilities from this website: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/
but I just cant to seem to get the methods parameters right and with right output.