# Java - Reflection Extract Class

Tags: java, reflection

This is my file (UPDATED):

```
     import java.lang.reflect.*;

public class ClassExtract {

   public void printClassDefinition (String[] args){
       try {
            Class cls = Class.forName(args[0]);
            Field fieldlist[] 
              = cls.getDeclaredFields();
            for (int i 
              = 0; i < ((fieldlist.length + 1) - (fieldlist.length)); i++) 
            {
                Field fld = fieldlist[i];
                System.out.println("+ " + fld.getDeclaringClass().toString().replaceAll("class", ""));
                System.out.println("------");
            }                              
               for (int j = 0; j < fieldlist.length; j++) {
                   Field fld1 = fieldlist[j];
                   int mod = fld1.getModifiers();
                   System.out.println(Modifier.toString(mod).toString().replaceAll("public", "+") 
                           .replaceAll("private", "-").replaceAll("protected", "#") + " " + 
                           fld1.getType() + " " + fld1.getName());

               }
            }
          catch (Throwable e) {
             System.err.println(e);
          }

   }
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
      new ClassExtract().printClassDefinition(args);

   }
}
```

and I am supposed to read this file:

```
    public class Complex{
    private int re;
    private int im;

    public Complex(int re, int im){
    this.re = re;
    this.im = im;
         }


    public Complex add(Complex h){
            return new Complex(this.re+h.re, this.im+h.im);
        }



    public Complex sub(Complex h){
    return new Complex(this.re-h.re, this.im-h.im);
        }

    public String toString(){
        if (im >= 0){
            return re +" + " +im + "i";
        }
        else return re +"  " +im + "i";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

    Complex c1 = new Complex(5,1);
    Complex c2 = new Complex(5,0);

    System.out.printf("c1 = %s, c2 = %s\n", c1, c2);
    System.out.printf("c1 + c2 = %s\n", c1.add(c2) );
     }}
```

and it should generate something like:

```
    (+) Complex
     ***
    (-) int re
    (-) int im
     ***
    (+) Complex(re:int, im:int)
    (+) add():Complex
    (+) sub():Complex
    (+) toString():String
    (+) main()
```

Since my file iterates through i get a print of "re" and "int" after the line for example, and my format is in general messed up. I could use all possible help. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java - Extract Interface to File](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9318961/java-extract-interface-to-file)

Comment: I need help with the first part.

I am supposed to get

    (+) Complex
     ***
    (-) int re
    (-) int re

but my output is 

+ Complex
-------
-int re
+ Complex

-------
-int im

Answer (score 3):

Sorry man, I am afraid your code is miles away from the solution, to send you the correct answer would be like cheating... I would recommend you the following approach though.

1. Create a function called printClassDefinition (Class clazz) This would print the first line of your otuput, once that you complete this, create a main method that only runs this part of your code, run it a couple of times and make sure that this function by itself produces the right output.
2. Create a function called printFields (Class clazz). This class loops through all the fields of your class and prints the name of the field only.
3. In the main you created in 1, add a print statement for your separator line, and call the function you have created in step 2. As in step 1, exercise your code and make sure that so far, you are happy with the results.
4. Create a function called printField (Field) Inside the loop of printFields, substitute your println function for a call to printField.
5. Now make your printField function print the correct output for each field.
6. Excercise again your main, your class and fields output should be spot on at this stage.
7. Similar to 2, create printMethods (Class clazz). Add this call to your main, and exercise.
8. Similar to 4, create printMehod (Method method) and substitute println in printMethods. And that's it!

Comment: I feel really bad at asking so much and im unfortunately not very good at programming, I am trying and trying my best - I have basically read almost two books page by page (Developing JAVA Software - Winder/Roberts & Java Essentials - Cay Horstmann) and googling almost all the time.

I will add my new current code to my mainpost, please tell me if I am on right track on atleast your first step - else I will reconsider quitting my course since I seem to not be able to comprehend basic programming.